# Dynamically Join Enum Table with other Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, enums

I have the following table. These are not the real tables but the concept is here.

```
Table1
----------------------------------
FieldID|EnumeratedValue|TextValue
----------------------------------
Col1    |1              |Hey
----------------------------------
Col1    |2              |Test
----------------------------------
Col1    |3              |George
----------------------------------
Col2    |1              |Random
----------------------------------
Col2    |2              |Wesley
----------------------------------
Col3    |1              |Tompson
----------------------------------
Col3    |2              |Oooo
----------------------------------
Table2
----------------------------------
Col1    |Col2           |Col3
----------------------------------
1       |2              |1
----------------------------------
2       |1              |1
----------------------------------
3       |1              |2
----------------------------------
```

The desired result would be a view

```
----------------------------------
Col1    |Col2           |Col3
----------------------------------
Hey     |Wesley         |Tompson
----------------------------------
Test    |Random         |Tompson
----------------------------------
George  |Random         |Oooo
----------------------------------
```

So you could write something like

```
   SELECT col1.TextValue,col2.TextValue,col3.TextValue
    FROM Table2 t2,
 (SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE FieldID = 'Col1') col1,
 (SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE FieldID = 'Col2') col2,
 (SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE FieldID = 'Col3') col3
    WHERE t2.col1 = col1.EnumeratedValue and t2.col2 = col2.EnumeratedValue and t2.col3 = col3.EnumeratedValue
```

The problem is that in our real tables there ~20 of these columns per table. I would like to find a simpler means of writing this code. I do not want to hard code 20 joins for each view that I am making. Let me know if there are any alternatives.

Comment: I don't get it. I tried see what the joins would do but it makes no sense, at all. Please make it more clear. And you can't compare t2.col1 (which is a number) with col1.FieldId (which is text). You would get no result. I understand what you want to do when I look at the desired output, but then I don't understand why you would want to do such a thing.

Comment: Juru I'm sorry, my logic was wrong. I've updated the query. The hope is to not have to hardcode all the (SELECT * FROM Table 1...).

Comment: @Juru we are using an enum table to save storage in our tables. We use EnumeratedTypes(ints) for the rest of our tables because redundant strings will waste a lot of space we cannot afford.

Comment: That looks better! You can't afford storing duplicate strings? How much data do you have? And how much is going to cost to store those things that way? Thought about storing the data compressed? Takes longer to retrieve but takes less storing space. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280449.aspx

Comment: This is a great alternative @Juru, but unfortunately this database is part of a 3rd party program that we outsourced. They will not change the schema or the way information is sent to the tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As with any variable join solution, a dynamic pivot is really the better way to look at this. It's not as performance as a hard-coded, non-pivot solution, but this will involve the least development hours, and can be adapted to generate view definitions rather than made into a table-valued function (which could be fed a table name and possibly column names to pivot and join)

First, the demo data setup:

```
if object_id('dbo.test_enum') is not null drop table dbo.test_enum
create table dbo.test_enum (
      FieldID sysname
    , EnumeratedValue int not null
    , TextValue sysname
    , primary key (FieldID, EnumeratedValue)
)
INSERT INTO dbo.test_enum
    (FieldID, EnumeratedValue, TextValue)
VALUES
    ('Col1', 1, 'Hey'),
    ('Col1', 2, 'Test'),
    ('Col1', 3, 'George'),
    ('Col2', 1, 'Random'),
    ('Col2', 2, 'Wesley'),
    ('Col3', 1, 'Tompson'),
    ('Col3', 2, 'Oooo')
;
if object_id('dbo.test_table') is not null drop table dbo.test_table
create table test_table (
      id int primary key identity(1,1)
    , Col1 int not null
    , Col2 int not null
    , Col3 int not null
);
INSERT INTO dbo.test_table
    (Col1, Col2, Col3)
VALUES
    (1,2,1),
    (2,1,1),
    (3,1,2)
```

Next is the dynamic selection part:

```
declare @cols nvarchar(max) = (select stuff((
    select ',' + quotename(c.name)
    from sys.objects o
        inner join sys.columns c on c.object_id = o.object_id
    where o.name = 'test_table'
        and c.name in ('Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3')
    for xml path ('')
    ),1,1,''))
declare @SQL nvarchar(max) = N'
select p.id, ' + @cols + '
from (
    select unp.id, unp.FieldID, e.TextValue
    from dbo.test_table
        unpivot (
            EnumeratedValues FOR FieldID IN (' + @cols + ')
        ) unp
        inner join dbo.test_enum e on e.EnumeratedValue = unp.EnumeratedValues
            and e.FieldID = unp.FieldID
    ) z
    pivot (
        min(z.TextValue) FOR z.FieldID IN (' + @cols + ')
    ) p
'
exec sp_executesql @sql
```

On its own, this will return the result set desired in the question, but can be adapted to return view definitions of any given table/column data set, and then further adapted per table/view.

Comment: This is fantastic Jaaz! Thank you for writing up this example for me!